# Weird stuff with SymmetricDS

Tags: tomcat, symmetricds

Lately, whenever I run `bin\sym` or start `war` in tomacat, SymmetricDS tries to create `sym-tables` like it's the first time I run it. This creates an error, as the table already exists. What's wrong with my configuration? I don't remember changing anything, but now nothing is working.

Also, I tried creating empty databases for nodes `server` and `client` and creating `item` table in `server` to test synchronization while deployed to Tomcat, but my `client` node cannot register with the following message:

```
[client] - RegistrationService - This node is unregistered.  It will attempt to register using the registration.url
[client] - DataLoaderService - Using registration URL of http://localhost:8080/server/sync/registration?nodeGroupId=client&externalId=001&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fclient%2Fsync&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=Firebird+2.53WI&databaseVersion=2.5&symmetricVersion=3.7.2&hostName=MSALNIKOV-PC&ipAddress=fe80%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A2555%3A61bf%3A940c%3A47e1%25eth7
[client] - RegistrationService - Could not register.  Sleeping before attempting again.
[client] - RegistrationService - Sleeping for 19000ms
```

And if I try and run it standalone I get the following issue:
[image]
(it looks unreadable, but I could not copy from console. You can copy image url or open it in new tab)

Can anyone help with that?

**Uppdate**

I downloaded a clean version of SymmetricDS and I was able to run the User Guide example from console, but when I make a `war` and deploy it to Tomcat, it tries to create sym-tables everytime artifact starts (when Tomcat starts or when I reload or stop/start it), which causes the `table already exists` error. What's wrong and why was it working ok earlier?